# Javascript unescape() vs. Python urllib.unquote()

Tags: javascript, python, escaping, urllib

From reading various posts, it seems like JavaScript's `unescape()` is equivalent to Pythons `urllib.unquote()`, however when I test both I get different results:

### In browser console:

```
unescape('%u003c%u0062%u0072%u003e');
```

*output:* `<br>`

### In Python interpreter:

```
import urllib
urllib.unquote('%u003c%u0062%u0072%u003e')
```

*output:* `%u003c%u0062%u0072%u003e`

I would expect Python to also return `<br>`. Any ideas as to what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`%uxxxx` is a [non standard URL encoding scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Non-standard_implementations) that is not supported by `urllib.parse.unquote()` (Py 3) / `urllib.unquote()` (Py 2).

It was only ever part of ECMAScript ECMA-262 3rd edition; the format was rejected by the W3C and was never a part of an RFC.

You could use a regular expression to convert such codepoints:

```
try:
    unichr  # only in Python 2
except NameError:
    unichr = chr  # Python 3

re.sub(r'%u([a-fA-F0-9]{4}|[a-fA-F0-9]{2})', lambda m: unichr(int(m.group(1), 16)), quoted)
```

This decodes both the `%uxxxx` and the `%uxx` form ECMAScript 3rd ed can decode.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> quoted = '%u003c%u0062%u0072%u003e'
>>> re.sub(r'%u([a-fA-F0-9]{4}|[a-fA-F0-9]{2})', lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1), 16)), quoted)
'<br>'
>>> altquoted = '%u3c%u0062%u0072%u3e'
>>> re.sub(r'%u([a-fA-F0-9]{4}|[a-fA-F0-9]{2})', lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1), 16)), altquoted)
'<br>'
```

but you should avoid using the encoding altogether if possible.

Comment: isn't `x.replace('%u',r'\u').decode('unicode-escape')` simpler?

Comment: @roippi: that presumes that all `%u` characters are part of an escaped codepoint. I wanted to play it a little safer than that.

Comment: true, but since b is escaped as `%u0062` I assume every single character is an escaped codepoint.

Comment: @roippi: I just checked the [ECMA-262 3rd edition standard (check page 171, B.2.2)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf); `%u` is also permitted (literal text), as is `%uxx` (equivalent to `%u00xx`). Using a simple `\u` replacement is not sufficient there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters diligent!  You've got it right then.