# Python urllib2.unquote() vs Javascript unescape()

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a string which I encoded with `python urllib2.quote()`. The string in question is `"Z%C3%BCrich"`, which was encoded from `"Zürich"`. However, there seems to be a discrepancy between the way python handles this and the way JavaScript does.

In python:

```
>>> print urllib2.unquote("Z%C3%BCrich")
Zürich
```

In JavaScript:

```
> unescape("Z%C3%BCrich")
'ZÃ¼rich'
```

These are taking in the same input string, but producing very different output strings. What am I doing wrong?

Note: This post is not a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158822/javascript-unescape-vs-python-urllib-unquote), in which the author had the opposite problem.

Comment: Try `decodeURI("Z%C3%BCrich")`.

Comment: Basically, `urllib2.quote()` is more like `encodeURI()` in JavaScript.  And `urllib2.unquote()` is `decodeURI()` rahter than `unescape()`. You should always avoid `escape()` and `unescape()` function in JavaScript because they'll give you weird output...like you're getting now.

Comment: Great, didn't know that. I'm experienced in Python but rather new to JavaScript. I appreciate the swift response. Since you answered first, if you post that as an answer I'll accept yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Posting my comments as an answer.</sub>

You should use:

```
decodeURI("Z%C3%BCrich")
```

Instead of `unescape("Z%C3%BCrich")` in JavaScript.

Basically, `urllib2.quote()` is more like `encodeURI()` in JavaScript.  And `urllib2.unquote()` is `decodeURI()` rahter than `unescape()`.

You should always avoid `escape()` and `unescape()` function in JavaScript because they'll give you weird output...like you're getting now.

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript function `unescape()` is deprecated, you should use `decodeURI()` instead. `unescape()` is giving you the utf-8 encoded form of your string rather than the unicode you want.

Comment: Thanks so much for the swift response, it works great.