# Decode %xx in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode

I have

`%64%6f%63%75%6d%65%6e%74%2e%77%72%69%74%65%28%27%3c%61%20%68%72%65%66%3d%22%6d%61%69%6c%74%6f%3a%62%65%6e%2e%61%6e%67%65%72%40%6b%6e%6f%62%62%65%2e%63%6f%6d%22%20%72%65%6c%3d%22%6e%6f%69%6e%64%65%78%2c%20%6e%6f%66%6f%6c%6c%6f%77%22%3e%62%65%6e%2e%61%6e%67%65%72%40%6b%6e%6f%62%62%65%2e%63%6f%6d%3c%2f%61%3e%27%29%3b`

It's from a JavaScript tag that I scraped.

Unfortunately, none of the solutions in [Javascript unescape() vs. Python urllib.unquote()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158822/javascript-unescape-vs-python-urllib-unquote) seem to work in Python 3.

Comment: [Javascript unescape() vs. Python urllib.unquote()](//stackoverflow.com/q/23158822) covers a different problem. Nevertheless, I updated it for Python 3 compatibility.

Comment: And here's to hoping that the lawyers at Knobbe.com don't mind their email addresses scraped. What were you planning to use those for?

Comment: it's a part of data collection project.If they are trying to prevent scraping or have strict no-scraping policy,they are not doing a great job at it apart from using deprecated encoding techniques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`unquote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) has been moved to the `urllib.parse` package in Python 3:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import unquote
>>> unquote('%64%6f%63%75%6d%65%6e%74%2e')
'document.'
```